# cannot check equality in ejs, it breaks rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, template-engine, ejs

So, in my node.js/express.js application I use ejs as view engine and in a ejs file I have

```
<%if (locals.user.role=1){%>
        <a href='/menu1'>menu1</a>
        <a href='/toolset1'>toolset1</a>
<% }else if (locals.user.role=2){%> 
        <a href='/menu1'>menu1</a>
        <a href='/toolset2'>toolset2</a>
<% } %>
```

According to user's role, I render different links. User's role is a number, is always 1 or 2. This file is included in another file like this

```
<%include menu%>
```

When I go to that page I get 
`Unexpected token = in "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\thisisgonnabeawesome\\views\\yourconsoletotakeovertheworld.ejs"`.

This error refers to `<%if (locals.user.role=1){%>` because if I remove the `<%include menu%>` the error goes away.

How do I check for equality in ejs ?

Thanks

Comment: try to insert spaces after `<%` and before `%>`

Comment: and you probably want to use `==` instead of `=` here ;)